# R Shiny plotly::plotlyProxyInvoke Update on subplot - Updates all traces/subplots not target plot of a subplot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Good afternoon,

I'm attempting to use the `plotly::plotlyProxyInvoke()` function to update the data in a single plot of a subplot. I'm having issues, however, as it appears the indices argument does not apply to the correct trace in a subplot. Each plot gets updated with the same data.

**Plot Before Update**
*Original Data*
[image]

**Plot After Update**
*The second plot 'hp' was targets to have 'Camero z28' set to 0. The code is doing that, but copying the data for hp, and applying it to disp, and mpg.*
[image]

**REPEX of my problem***

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

cars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = "carname") %>% 
  arrange(carname) %>% 
  select(carname, cyl, mpg, hp, disp) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(carname, cyl))

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myplot", height = '600px'),
  actionButton("update", "Update Data"), 
  numericInput('newValue', "New hp Value", 0), 
  selectInput(inputId = "carName", "Car Name", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, choices = cars$carname, selected = unique(cars$carname[1]))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({

    pp <- cars %>%
      group_by(name) %>%
      do(p =
           plot_ly(data = .) %>%
           add_bars(
             x = ~carname,
             y = ~value
             # color = ~cyl
           ) %>%
           layout(showlegend = F, yaxis = list(title = ~unique(name)))
      ) %>%
    subplot(nrows = 3, titleY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE, shareX = FALSE, shareY = FALSE)  
  
    pp

  })
   
  observeEvent(input$update, {

    cars2 <- cars %>% 
      filter(name == "hp") %>% 
      rows_update(., tibble(carname = input$carName, value = input$newValue))

    proxy <- plotlyProxy("myplot", session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain())

    proxy %>% plotlyProxyInvoke("update",
                                y = list(cars2$value),
                                x = list(cars2$carname),
                                #Defining the index here is not helping? 
                                as.integer(1) #either does this. 
                                # list(list(1)) #this doesn't work
    )

  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the modified `plotlyProxyInvoke` call:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

cars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = "carname") %>% 
  arrange(carname) %>% 
  select(carname, cyl, mpg, hp, disp) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(carname, cyl))

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myplot", height = '600px'),
  actionButton("update", "Update Data"), 
  numericInput('newValue', "New hp Value", 0), 
  selectInput(inputId = "carName", "Car Name", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, choices = unique(cars$carname), selected = cars$carname[1])
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({
    
    pp <- cars %>%
      group_by(name) %>%
      do(p =
           plot_ly(data = .) %>%
           add_bars(
             x = ~carname,
             y = ~value
             # color = ~cyl
           ) %>%
           layout(showlegend = F, yaxis = list(title = ~unique(name)))
      ) %>%
      subplot(nrows = 3, titleY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE, shareX = FALSE, shareY = FALSE)  
    
    pp
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    cars2 <- cars %>% 
      filter(name == "hp") %>% 
      rows_update(., tibble(carname = input$carName, value = input$newValue))
    proxy <- plotlyProxy("myplot", session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain())
    proxy %>% plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(y = list(cars2$value), x = list(cars2$carname)), list(0L))
    # update = restyle + relayout # subplots share a single layout
    # proxy %>% plotlyProxyInvoke("update", list(y = list(cars2$value), x = list(cars2$carname)), list(0L))
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As a side note, I do have a question, as I wasn't able to answer from Plotly's documentation. When restyling, does it redraw all of the data points or only the ones that are different?

Comment: @JordanWebb with [Plotly.restyle](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) we are modifying the data array in an existing plot (it is not redrawing the whole plot) - however, in the above case we are replacing all datapoints for the selected trace. [Plotly.update](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate) is intended to update the data array and layout object in an existing plot - and as already commented in the code the lyout is shared among subplots.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking, I've included the updated code and made some changes to allow updating with the color variable being active. It requires identifying which trace number the edit contains. See below.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

cars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = "carName") %>% 
  select(carName, cyl, mpg, hp, disp) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(carName, cyl), names_to = "metricName", values_to = "metricValue") %>% 
  mutate(metricName = as.factor(metricName)) %>% 
  arrange(metricName, cyl, carName)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3, selectInput(inputId = "carName", "Car Name", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, width = '100%', choices = unique(cars$carName), selected = cars$carName[1])),
    column(width = 3, selectInput(inputId = "metricName", "Metric Name", multiple = FALSE, width = '100%', selectize = TRUE, choices = unique(cars$metricName), selected = cars$metricName[1])),
    column(width = 3, numericInput('newValue', "New hp Value", 0, width = '100%',)), 
    column(width = 3, actionButton("update", "Update Data", width = '100%', style = 'margin-top: 25px;'))
  ),
  plotlyOutput("myplot", height = '600px')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({
    
    pp <- cars %>%
      group_by(metricName) %>%
      do(p =
           plot_ly(data = .) %>%
           add_bars(
             x = ~carName,
             y = ~metricValue, 
             color = ~cyl
           ) %>%
           layout(showlegend = F, yaxis = list(title = ~unique(metricName)))
      ) %>%
      subplot(nrows = 3, titleY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE, shareX = FALSE, shareY = FALSE)  
    
    pp
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    
    metricNameSelected <- input$metricName
    carNameSelected <- input$carName
    cylSelected <- cars %>% filter(carName == carNameSelected, metricName == metricNameSelected) %>% pull(cyl)
    
    #Get Trace ID For update
    idx <- cars %>% 
      arrange(metricName, cyl) %>% 
      select(metricName, cyl) %>% 
      unique() %>% 
      group_by(metricName, cyl) %>% 
      count() %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(idx = cumsum(n)-1) %>% 
      filter(metricName == metricNameSelected) %>% 
      filter(cyl == cylSelected) %>% 
      pull(idx)

    cars2 <- cars %>% 
      filter(metricName == metricNameSelected) %>% 
      filter(cyl == cylSelected) %>% 
      rows_update(., tibble(carName = carNameSelected, metricValue = input$newValue))

    proxy <- plotlyProxy("myplot", session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain())
    proxy %>% plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", 
                                list(
                                  y = list(cars2$metricValue), 
                                  x = list(cars2$carName)
                                ), 
                                list(idx)
                              )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```